# Printing larger numbers with batch script

Tags: batch-file, cmd

When I am printing these numbers in batch script they are displaying some values other than these numbers ,how to print these values in windows?

for /L %%n in (181729000010,1,181729000012) do echo %%n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the purpose of your question example, just change the command to:

```dos
For /L %%A In (29000010,1,29000012) Do Echo 1817%%A
```

Comment: Snap!  52 seconds earlier!

Comment: I suppose `For /L %%A In (0,1,2) Do Echo 18172900001%%A` would have been a little tidier.

Answer (score 2):

This is called an integer overflow. Batch can only handle numbers up to `2^31 -1 = 2147483647` as it only works with 32bit integers.

The answer to your question is: it's impossible.

However, if it is all just about **printing**, there is no problem:

```
ECHO 181729000010
```

works just fine. It's because in this case it is handled as a string and not as a number. But as soon as you try to do calculations with numbers bigger than 2147483647, you will fail.

Your code `for /L %%n in (181729000010,1,181729000012) do echo %%n` iterates over numbers from 181729000010 to 181729000012 which means, it adds 1 to the index in each iteration starting with `181729000010 + 1` which **is a calculation**.

Comment: so windows machine cannot calculate and process long integers of 64 bit as in Linux!!!

Comment: A windows machine can, `cmd.exe` cannot.

Answer (score 1):

```
for /L %%n in (9000010,1,9000012) do echo 18172%%n
```

should operate quite happily to do what you ask.

If you show us your actual problem, we may be able to suggest a solution. You appear to have asked us to fix a solution to an unknown problem.

Answer (score 1):

I know you already have a solution. Here is one that works with numbers.

```
FOR /F %%i IN (
    'powershell.exe -NoProfile -Command ^
        "for ($i=181729000010; $i -le 181729000012; $i++) { $i }"'
) DO (ECHO %%i)
```

Note that the PowerShell Range operator `..` is limited to [int32] sized numbers.